# ¿Cómo referenciar valor de @ModelAttribute en Mockito?

Tags: java, test, mockito

Quería saber cómo puedo pasar el @ModelAttribute en Mockito para poder testear un método POST del controlador.

En el controlador tengo dos atributos anotados con @ModelAttribute y los tengo que pasar en Mockito para poder testear ese método del controlador. Los @ModelAttribute son dos Double y me lanza un error de Invalid use of argument matchers y no sé como solucionarlo.

Adjunto el código del test del método del controlador:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class TestUserLoginController {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private MockMvc mockMvcRedirect;

    private UserService service;

    private ImageService imageService;

    public TestUserLoginController() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public final void setUpMockContext() throws InstanceNotFoundException {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(getUserController())
                .alwaysExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).build();

        mockMvcRedirect = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(getUserController())
                .alwaysExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is3xxRedirection()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testBestUserImagesController() throws Exception {
        mockMvcRedirect.perform(postBestImages());
    }

    private final UserLoginController getUserController() throws InstanceNotFoundException {
        this.service = Mockito.mock(UserService.class);
        this.imageService = Mockito.mock(ImageService.class);

        return new UserLoginController(service, imageService);
    }

    private final RequestBuilder postBestImages() {
        List<Image> userImages = new ArrayList<>();

        Mockito.when(imageService.getAllUserImages(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(userImages);

        return MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/user/login/bestImages").flashAttr("longitud", Mockito.anyDouble())
                .flashAttr("latitud", Mockito.anyDouble());
    }
}
```

En el siguiente método que voy a adjuntar se encuentran los @ModelAttribute

Método el método del controlador:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserLoginController {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final ImageService imageService;

    @Autowired
    public UserLoginController(final UserService userService, final ImageService imageService) {
        super();

        this.userService = checkNotNull(userService, "Received a null pointer as service");
        this.imageService = checkNotNull(imageService, "Received a null pointer as service");
    }



   @PostMapping("/login/bestImages")
   public final String showBestImages (final ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("longitud") double longitud, @ModelAttribute("latitud") double latitud, HttpServletRequest request) {

        List<Image> bestImages;
        BestImageOutput defaultOutput;

        bestImages = getImageService().getBestUsersImages("Coruna");

        // imagen por defecto
        defaultOutput = new BestImageOutput();

        // si no hay elementos, mostramos imagen por defecto
        if (bestImages.isEmpty()) {
            defaultOutput.setPath(UtilConstants.DEFAULT_IMAGE);
            defaultOutput.setNoImage(true);
        } else {
            Image defaultImage = bestImages.remove(0);
            defaultOutput.setPath(defaultImage.getPath());
            defaultOutput.setNoImage(false);
        }

        // foto que mostramos por defecto
        model.put(UserViewConstants.DEFAULT_IMAGE, defaultOutput);

        // lista de fotos obtenidas
        model.put(ImageViewConstants.IMAGES_CAROUSEL, ControllerMethods.outputListBest(bestImages));

        return "fragments/bestImages";
    }
```

El error que me muestra al ejecutar los test es el siguiente:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
```

y a la línea a la que se refiere es a la siguiente:

```
return MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/user/login/bestImages").flashAttr("longitud", Mockito.anyDouble())
            .flashAttr("latitud", Mockito.anyDouble());
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias